# Solidworks Z-axis Tolerances

Tags: solidworks, tolerance

I have a fresnel lens made by a company that has z-axis steps in it at the 10s of micron scale. That's fine except that it creates weird optical effects that I am having trouble simulating. I have a good CAD model of the lens, but I need to figure out how to add these z-axis steps / surface roughness. Does anyone have an idea how I can do that? Note: I'm on SW 2018.

Comment: Im not sure i understand what the aswer could be? I mean you adjust your preciscion and model them in but beyond that no idea

Comment: So I was hoping there was... some cam processor or something I could apply to take this to make something with z cut tolerances.

Comment: You could model it as such with equation driven sketches.

Comment: Hmm, a very interesting concept. It might take a fair amount of work, as fresnel lenses are pretty complicated geometries - but that may be worth it.